# Is there any preferred situation to use "denn" vs "weil"?

Tags: etymology, conjunction, semantics

I was thinking of my last question, where I asked if the type of clause after a connective decides the word order and by default the word order after using specific words. After thinking,I realised that there are two words that mean because: one that doesn't change word order and one that sends verbs to the end. Is there any reason be it semantically or etymologically that can explain this?

Comment: Die Frage beruht auf einer falschen annahme. Denn ließt man alte Texte, so findet sich auch der andere Satzbau. "Denn wenn" dürfte dagegen neu sein.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think that etymology may help here. "Denn" is followed by a main clause, "weil" is followed by a subordinate clause. I (being German) would say that "denn" is somewhat stronger. However, you won't hear"denn" very often in spoken German, usually it will be "weil".

Comment: It should be noted that current usage is changing fast so that *weil* is used with the word order of *denn*, no matter how strongly language purists object. In twenty years the question will be moot.

Comment: Well, - "Ich kann nicht kommen, weil ich habe keine Zeit." - sth like this is generally still regarded as wrong. However it can be heard quite often: typical German spoken by migrants, especially from Turkey.

Answer (score 2):

A clause with *denn* is less dependent of the main clause, which may even be missing or in a separate sentence. The fact that the word order is the same as in a main clause is in accordance with this.

Because of this *denn* can be used if a clause is not only there to substantiate the main clause but if it's an important statement in its own right.

As a side note, there is a similar pair of words in English: *Because* and *for*. *Because* corresponds to *weil*, and *for* (as a conjunction) is similar to *denn*.

Compare common translations of Matthew 7:13:

> [...] **Denn** die Pforte ist weit und der Weg ist breit, der zur Verdammnis führt, und viele sind's, die auf ihm hineingehen.

English:

> [...] **For** wide is the gate and broad is the road that leads to destruction, and many enter through it.